# About uniform convergence in Hille-Yosida's Theorem proof

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, uniform-convergence, semigroup-of-operators

In every proof of H-Y's Theorem (the sufficiency part) that I saw, some form of uniform convergence is mentioned, in a very terse way. 
It goes like this, following Pazy's book: since, for every $x$ in a Banach space $X$ and $\lambda,\,\mu > 0$, one has $$\left\| \exp(t A_\lambda)(x) - \exp(t A_\mu)(x)\right\| \leqslant t\left\|A_\lambda(x) - A_\mu(x) \right\|, $$
for $t \geqslant 0$, in which $A_\lambda$ is the Yosida approximation of a linear operator $A$ satisfying the hipothesis of H-Y's Theorem (this is Lemma 3.4 in Pazy's book) and $A_\lambda(x) \longrightarrow A(x)$, as $\lambda \longrightarrow \infty$ (this is Lemma 3.3 in Pazy's book), for $x$ in the domain of $A$, Pazy then writes that $(\exp(t A_\lambda)(x))_{\lambda}$ converges *uniformly* on bounded intervals of the form $[0,\,t_0]$. 
That said, I'm struggling to understand what kind of uniform convergence is this, since, a priori, is not related to the strong operator topology at all.
That put, how can I understand this statement? 
Since we're talking about taking $\lambda \longrightarrow \infty$, where $\lambda$ is any positive real number, this looks like it is related to the concept of a net, which I have very little acquaintance with, or it could be much simpler than that. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $\exp(tA_{\lambda})x$ converges uniformly as $\lambda\rightarrow \infty$ for a fixed $x$ and for all $t$ in any given finite interval $[0,a]$. That guarantees that the limit function $V(t)=``e^{tA}"$ is such that $e^{tA}x$ is strongly continuous in $t$ on $[0,\infty)$ for a fixed $x$, and it also guarantess that $\lim_{t\downarrow 0}e^{tA}x=x$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts I'm struggling to understand the uniform convergence for a fixed $x$. If we considerar positive integers as indexes, your sentence translates to $\exp(tA_n)(x)$ converges uniformly as $n \longrightarrow \infty$, for a fixed $x$ and for all $t$ in any finite interval $[0,\,a]$. To talk about uniform convergence, in the sup metric in the space of continuous functions $C\left([0,\,a],\,X\right)$, it cannot depend on $x$, right? I mean, the sequence $(\exp(t A_n))_{n\,\in\,\mathbb{N}})$ converges uniformly to $\exp(tA)$ as the sup of the norms converges to $0$, for each $x$.

Comment: Keep in mind that the goal of showing uniform convergence is that $e^{tA}x$ is continuous in $t$ for $t \ge 0$ for a fixed $x$. You can discuss using convergence in the operator norm, but that only happens when the generator is bounded, which is not the interesting case for $C_0$ semigroups.